# Insert table column value in the Php Session

Tags: php

in my mysql database I have table called users which has primary key column called userID which is Auto Increment column. I would like to get inside the session array the value of this column for the logged in user, here is how the array looks like right now:

`array(4) { ["loggedIn"]=> bool(true) ["username"]=> string(9) "user" ["password"]=> string(3) "123" ["userID"]=> NULL }`

This is the code of my login form:

```
session_start();
$usr = new Users;
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );
if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
header( 'Location: cursos.php' ) ;
$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
$_SESSION['userID'] = $_POST['userID'];
```

and this is my login function:

```
public function userLogin() {
$success = false;
try{
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );

$stmt->execute();

$valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if( $valid ) {
    $success = true;
}

$con = null;
return $success;
```

what I need is at the end in my session array to have `["userID"]=>` the value fro the column userID from table users of the loged user. 
How this can be acheived ? If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Is your userid really passed in the form ($_POST)? It looks like you should be receiving that value from your db lookup in userLogin(). If there is no userID value in your form, you're setting it to null with your `$_SESSION['userID'] = $_POST['userID'];` statement.

Comment: what I need is at the end in my session array to have ["userID"]=> the value fro the column userID from table users of the loged user.